# pdftotxt page number selector

Tags: pdf

How can I convert a pdf file pages to txt file seperately.

My example code;

```
pdftotext test.pdf x.txt
```

My php example code;

```
 for($i=1; $i<4; $i++){
    if(shell_exec("pdftotext -f $i test.pdf test/t$i.txt")){
        echo 'selam';
    }
 }
```

But this don't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pdftotext` program will insert a form feed character (`\f`) after each PDF page. You can use this to split your text file into multiple files, one per page. First run the command you normally run:

```
pdftotext test.pdf x.txt
```

Then, split:

```
awk -vk=1 '/\f/{k++}{print >> k".txt"}' x.txt
```

The `awk` command will first set the variable `k` to `1` (`-vk=1`) and then increment the variable by 1 each time a form feed character is found on a line (`/\f/{k++}`). Then, it will print each line to a file whose name is the current value of `k`, plus the string `.txt` (`print >> k".txt"`). So, running the script above on a text file containing a converted 5-page PDF file will result in `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`, `4.txt` and `5.txt`.

Note that the script will *append* to each text file, so running it twice will just add to existing files (if any). To avoid that, remove the files before attempting to run again.

To integrate it into your php code, use:

```
for($i=1; $i<4; $i++){
    if(shell_exec("pdftotext -f $i test.pdf test/t$i.txt")){
        echo 'selam';
    }
    if(shell_exec("awk -vk=1 -vi="$i" '/\f/{k++}{print >> i"."k".txt"}' t$i.txt")){
        echo 'selam';
    }

}
```